# How can i take the TaskEventArgs from a control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, telerik

Am using Telerik RadGantt chart. i need to insert the event to the data base for that am using the code as given:

```
Private Sub RadGantt1_TaskUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.Gantt.TaskEventArgs) Handles RadGantt1.TaskUpdate 
            mssql = "insert into project " & _
                    " (ParentID, OrderID, Title, Start, End, PercentComplete, Expanded, Summary)" & _
                    " values('E1','" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.ID & "', " & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.Title & "'," & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.Start & "'," & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.End & "'," & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.PercentComplete & "'," & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.Expanded & "'," & _
                    " '" & e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.Summary & "')"
            Dim mycommand As OdbcCommand
            mycommand = New OdbcCommand(mssql, dbcon)
            dbcon.Open()
            Dim mnresult As Integer = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If mnresult = 1 Then
                EventAdd = False
            End If
         End Sub
```

But it gives an object reference error in `e.Tasks.GetEnumerator.Current.ID`. then how can i take the value from this event?

Answer (score 0):

e.Tasks is a collection so you should iterate through it (e.g., in a for..each loop).

To get a single tasks whose properties you can read you should use the enumerator of the collection, for example e.Tasks(1).GetEnumerator.Current.ID